# Eclipse won't compile SWT file properly after SFTP transfer

Tags: eclipse, swt, sftp

I was coding earlier today using Textastic 9 on my iPhone today using files I had downloaded over SFTP. I sent them back to my computer (the whole project transferred to my phone), and now three of the four work. They compile correctly, and the colour coding works perfectly. The last one, however, only colour codes specific keywords and strings. It won't accept variable names and anything from a separate library/file, say `org.eclipse.swt.SWT`.

Here's a screenshot of that file: 
[image: StackOverflow makes me use a link.]

Here's another file that also went through SFTP that's working perfectly: [image: StackOverflow makes me use a link.]

I'm also getting the error `Syntax error on tokens, SimpleName expected` on a `return;` statement. I've also tried pasting the code in Notepad, deleting the file, and pasting it into a new file. That doesn't work.

Thanks to @Ros5292

It turns out the display() method had parameters with incorrect capitalisation. I fixed this, clicked on the Design tab, selected the root method, and it *compiles*. It still doesn't allow me to use other files, color code, etc.

Comment: What does right clicking on the file and selecting 'Open With' show for the editor - it should be 'Java Editor'.

Comment: Istn't your declaration has problem ? `string` should be `String` in display method arguments ?

Comment: @greg-449 No, it has to be WindowBuilder. But even if it is Java Editor nothing changes

Comment: @Ros5292 That works for compiling, but not for the color-coding thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ros5292

It turns out the display() method had parameters with incorrect capitalisation. I fixed this, clicked on the Design tab, selected the root method, and it works. The colour coding and stuff were messed up due to a few errors because the file was technically new, and it hadn't compiled properly for the first time ever.